# Automorphisms of splitting field of $x^p-x-a$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

Let $p$ be a prime and consider the splitting field of $f(x) = x^{p} - x - a$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.  I have worked out that the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\beta)$, where $\beta$ is a root of $f$.  Then the maps $\tau^{n}$, where $\tau: \beta \mapsto \beta + 1$ permute the roots, but I am having trouble seeing that they are actually automorphisms.  For example,
$$\tau(\beta + (\beta + k)) = \beta + (\beta + k) + 1,\\
\tau(\beta) + \tau(\beta + k) = \beta + 1 + (\beta + k) + 1.$$
What am I missing?

Comment: You got the action of $\tau$ wrong. The elements of the splitting field are of the form $z=a_0+a_1\beta+a_2\beta^2+\cdots+a_{p-1}\beta^{p-1}$. And here
$$\tau(z)=a_0+a_1(\beta+1)+a_2(\beta+1)^2+\cdots+a_{p-1}(\beta+1)^{p-1}$$ for all $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{p-1}\in\Bbb{F}_p$. $\tau(z)=z+1$ does not hold universally. Only when $z=\beta$. (See Gaston's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map sends $\beta \mapsto \beta + 1$ but not $x \mapsto x+1$ for all $x\in F_p(\beta)$ this is your mistake:

$$\tau(\beta+(\beta+k))\neq \beta+(\beta+k)+1.$$

For example if $k\in F_p$, $\tau(k)=k$ but $\tau(k)\neq k+1$.

Comment: You read the question to the end, the others, while writing ok but oft repeated stuff, were on autopilot! +1 for that.

Comment: Because, clearly, it should be $\tau(\beta + (\beta + k))=\tau(2\beta+k)=2\beta+2+k$ which matches from the other direction.  I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Since the map
$$ u\to u^p $$
is an automorphism (the Frobenius' automorphism) of $\mathbb{F}_p(\beta)\simeq\mathbb{F}_{p^p}$, the roots of your polynomial are:
$$\xi,\xi^p,\xi^{p^2},\ldots,\xi^{p^{p-1}}.$$
But since $\xi^p = \xi+a$ this is the same as saying:
$$\xi, \xi+a,\xi^p+a,\ldots,\xi^{p^{p-2}}+a,$$
or just:
$$\xi, \xi+a,\xi+2a,\ldots,\xi+(p-1)a,$$
hence:
$$\xi,\xi+1,\ldots,\xi+(p-1).$$
This also follows from the rather simple fact that:
$$ x^p-x = \prod_{\nu\in\mathbb{F}_p}(x-\nu). $$

Answer (score 0):

I would cheat and use the fact $u \to u^p$ is an automorphism. In fact, this always generates the automorphism group of a finite field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Another plan would be to use the characterization of homomorphisms with domain $\mathbf{F}_p(\beta)$ to show that there is a unique homomorphism $\mathbf{F}_p(\beta) \to \mathbf{F}_p(\beta)$ that sends $\beta \to \beta + 1$

You could also piece something together using the fact $f(x) = f(x+1)$.

Another starting point is that the automorphism group has to be order $p$, but it also has to act transitively on the set of $p$ roots.